# Where in Paris can I rent a Segway without a guide?

Tags: paris, sightseeing

I would like to find some place to rent a segway by a whole day. I don't need a guide. Is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Searching for self-guided segway rental on Google, I came across [Gyropode](https://www.viator.com/tours/Paris/Segway-Type-Scooters-Renting-Paris/d479-18317P4)

> Upon arrival, you will be provided with training and safety
>   instruction before starting your independent tour. After that, you
>   will be free to explore the city of Paris independently and at your
>   own pace for either one or two hours depending on the option you have
>   selected.

Comment: "by a whole day"

Answer (score 4):

It's impossible to rent a Segway for all day, for a simple reason: they have a maximum autonomy of a couple of hours/12 kilometers (when not perfectly new). That's one of the main reason in most cities they are not rented (usually, at least) outside an organized tour: you'll end up with hundreds of customers everywhere accross the city to go to pick up 'cause they have no more autonomy left.

And, in a huge city like Paris, just from Arc de Triomphe to Notre-Dame de Paris it's 6 kilometers; by casually going around you would end up without charge left even before having seen a tenth of the city.

Comment: It is, obviously, an entirely different thing. A car rental company charge you tons of money so that when the customer is an idiot it's christmas time, they rent "few" cars, and they are not coming to pick you up, so when the hypotetical idiot drive for 200 kilometers and the car stop it is his problem to call a tow car, pay for it, and then they will make you pay more for each additional day you keep the car. Totally different from having a tens of segways accross the city that you are forced to go recover personally.

Comment: They already do, partially: that's the reason the one and only segway free rental you found in Paris cost for 2 hours on average more than the rental of a segway and a specialized guide for 3 hours. I'm not saying that you can't rent a segway without a guide, I'm just pointing out that you can't rent it for a whole day, as the OP asked.

Comment: (side note: obviously you can "charge the customer x00 euro if they don't return the segway too", but then you need at least a couple of van or three to go recover the segways, and then you need a bigger place for your activity because you need to park the vans, and you have vans that produce no income but just costs, and you must have spare peoples to drive them...all of this, to offer a worse service at an higher price? Really the fact that you found only ONE free rental in Paris vs tens of rental companies with tour included do not make you ring the bell that maybe there is a reason?)

Comment: I guess this company that does weeky segway rentals must have a full time job recovering them from all over the city when the customer abandoms them after two hours: http://segwayofrichmond.biz/tours-rentals/rental-rates/